# Rails creating nil record when calling User.all in the console

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Everytime I go into the rails console and call User.all, the active record creates a nil record and saves it.  I think it has something to do with my before_save callback.  I'm trying to have a user enter in a current weight, then make it's starting weight the same.

**Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weigh_ins
  has_many :comments

  mount_uploader :attachment, ImageUploader
  before_save :equalize_weights, on: create

  private

  def equalize_weights
    self.starting_weight = self.current_weight
  end

end
```

**users_constroller.rb create method**

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html {redirect_to @user, notice: 'User has been created successfully'}
    else
      format.html {render action: 'new'}
    end
  end
end
```

**Rails console**

```
irb(main):001:0> User.all
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (4.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)     [["created_at", Sat, 04 Jan 2014 04:21:21 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 04 Jan 2014    04:21:21 UTC +00:00]]
```

(1.4ms)  commit transaction

Comment: Is that your complete User model?  I don't think any of the above is responsible for the record creation.

Comment: Yes, it is the complete user model.  I think it's the before_save callback because when I comment it out, it doesn't create the extra record